# How do I redirect to sub directory only if I have a /blog/ URI

Tags: .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
  # getting no_script_name to work
  #RewriteBase /

  # we skip all files with .something
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  #RewriteRule .* - [L]

  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f


  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

# we redirect to blog if requested
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
  RewriteRule .* /blog/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Hi there, I am not that good with a htaccess yet, just need a quick help. 
the file above redirects everything to "blog" subdirectory.
How can I make sure that only url/blog/ gets redirected and all the rest does as it should?
thanks

What I want is:

1. url that is not domain/blog to act as normal and point to "web/index.php"
2. Only the "domain/blog" to point as "web/blog/index.php"

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. It sounds like you want `/blog/` to redirect to `/blog/`. Provide some example URLs and what you'd like them to rewrite into.

Comment: Hi I have added more description. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Right, this is probably very simplified for your needs.  Unless both the `web` and `blog` use good Front Controller models that just need to have the server redirect to them.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteBase /

  # skip all files that exist
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # match anything that starts with /blog/ to the blog index
  RewriteRule ^/blog/ /web/blog/index.php [L,QSA]

  # everything else to /web/index.php
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```